# Warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type in linked list struct

Tags: c, pointers, doubly-linked-list

I get a lot of "assignment from incompatible pointer type" warnings, and I don't know why.
The warnings appear in this part:

```
void addNode(linkedList* list, int board)
{
Node* newNode = createNode(board);
(list->last)->next = newNode; // this line has warning
newNode->prev = list->last; // this line has warning
}
```

The structs and the rest of the code is:

```
typedef struct{
    int board;
    struct Node* next;
    struct Node* prev;
}Node;

typedef struct{
    int length;
    Node* first;
    Node* last;
}linkedList;

Node* createNode(int board)
{
    Node* node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    node->next = NULL;
    node->prev = NULL;
    node->board = board;
    return node;
}
linkedList* createList()
{
    linkedList* list = (linkedList*)malloc(sizeof(linkedList));
    list->first = NULL;
    list->last = NULL;
    list->length = 0;
    return list;
 }
```

Comment: Besides what the answers pointed out, please note that in the `addNode` function `list->last` is dereferenced (`(list->last)->next = newNode;`) without checking if it's NULL (empty list).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This ...

> ```
> typedef struct{
>     int board;
>     struct Node* next;
>     struct Node* prev;
> }Node;
> ```

... declares a tagless structure type, and defines `Node` as an alias for that type.  It *does not* define the type `struct Node` to which its members `next` and `prev` point.  That doesn't prevent pointers to such a type being declared, but that type is not the same as `Node`, and not compatible with it.

The easiest solution, supposing that there isn't any definition of `struct Node` elsewhere, is to just add that tag:

```
typedef struct Node {
    int board;
    struct Node* next;
    struct Node* prev;
}Node;
```

That gives you what you surely meant.

Note, too, that you don't inherently need a `typedef` at all.  Having added the tag, you can refer to that type everywhere as `struct Node`.  The `typedef`'d alias is a convenience only, and one that I think is way overused.  All too often, `typedef`s obfuscate more than they help.

Answer (score 1):

You never actually define `struct Node`.

The type which you alias (`typedef`) as `Node` is an untagged `struct`. When you later declare a pointer `struct Node*`, the compiler allows it as a pointer to an incomplete type (which is implicitly declared), but that's not the same as any type declared in your program.

A good way to declare a struct with self-referring pointers is:

```
typedef struct Node Node;
struct Node {
    int board;
    Node* next;
    Node* prev;
};
```

In that formulation, the first line defines `Node` as an alias for the still incomplete type `struct Node`, which is then defined by the second declaration. `struct Node` is still incomplete when the `Node*` member declarations are encountered, but pointers to incomplete types are allowed.

One reason I'm fond of that style is that it works well with the common case in which the `struct` is an opaque datatype whose members are not intended for public use. In that case, the `typedef` can be placed in the header file, allowing pointers to the opaque type to be used in function prototypes or as local variables. The `struct` definition itself then goes into the implementation.